# How to configure axios to request to particluar <domain_name>/<path> just by writing path without having to hardcode domain name every time

Tags: python, django, reactjs, heroku, axios

Hey guys I am doing a project that uses Python as a backend and React as a frontend. Everything works fine. After deploying to heroku I changed all my axios request URL to my domain name. But I realize if I change my domain name I have to change the axios URL in my react app everytime. I have used redux to do perform axios request for CRUDL and all types of authentication. I know this sounds stupid but is there a way to configure all the axios request to particular domain name by only giving path name every time it makes request? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

setup axios defaults something like this:

```
axios.defaults.baseURL =
  process.env.NODE_ENV === "production"
    ? process.env.REACT_APP_PROD_URL
    : process.env.REACT_APP_DEV_URL;
```

then in your .env file

```
REACT_APP_PROD_URL="https://api.example.com"
REACT_APP_DEV_URL="http://localhost:8000"
```